# Load response from request to element instead of refreshing entire document

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i'm trying to make an ajax-browsing website, so whenever the user makes a request to another page i want to push that page into an element instead of loading an entire fresh page.

scenarios include:

- clicking on a link.
- ajax calls.
- manual : location.href = 'url';
- pretty much whenever a request is being made.

How can i take control of a request and put the result in an element instead of loading a fresh new page ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's usually better if you actually put a question in your question.  Which exact piece of this do you need help with?  What have you researched so far?  What have you tried so far?  Also, are you aware of iframes which make this pretty trivial if an iframe works for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily with [Ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify). It's really easy to use and has cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: do you know if that keeps javascript intact? we tried something like this a while back and it worked for static content, but our media galleries and other jQuery-plugin-based tools never got initialized because $.ready() never re-fired...